# What am i doing wrong with this regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
links = re.findall('href="(http(s?)://[^"]+)"',page)
```

I have this regular expression to find all links in a website, I am getting this result:

```
('http://asecuritysite.com', '')
('https://www.sans.org/webcasts/archive/2013', 's')
```

When what I want is only this:

```
http://asecuritysite.com
https://www.sans.org/webcasts/archive/2013
```

If I eliminate the `"(` after the href it gives me loads of errors, can someone explain why?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: If you eliminate just one parenthesis, you end up with unbalanced parentheses (which are used to denote capture groups), which is a syntax error (of sorts). Why would you remove that parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the second group (the `(s?)` in your original pattern):

```
links = re.findall('href="(https?:\/\/[^"]+)"',page)
```

Comment: @user2988983 *falsetru* has provided an [excellent explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20248449/1715579). Basically, using multiple capture groups causes the result to be formatted this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you use more than 1 capturing group, `re.findall` return list of tuples instead of list of strings. Try following (only using single group):

```
>>> import re
>>> page = '''
...     <a href="http://asecuritysite.com">here</a>
...     <a href="https://www.sans.org/webcasts/archive/2013">there</a>
...     '''
>>> re.findall(r'href="(https?:\/\/[^"]+)"',page)
['http://asecuritysite.com', 'https://www.sans.org/webcasts/archive/2013']
```

According to [`re.findall` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a **list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group.**

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is trying to parse HTML with Regex. And that sir, is a sin.

[See here for the horrors of Regex parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

An alternative is to use something like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to parse the page and extract the links something like this

```
urls = html.xpath('//a/@href')
```

Comment: Actually (as many comments in that link also point out) OP is _not_ parsing HTML, but rather simply searching for a string matching a pattern.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that he isn't trying to parse html

Comment: @iamnotmaynard its especially scary as he is regex searching a `page` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run into problems too if it's a single quote before the `https?` instead of double.

`(https?:\/\/[^\"\'\>]+)` will capture the entire string; what you could then do is prepend `(href=.?)` to it, and you'd end up with two capture groups:

Full regex: `(href=.?)(https?:\/\/[^\"\'\>]+)`

MATCH 1

- [Group 1] `href='`
- [Group 2] `http://asecuritysite.com`

MATCH 2

- [Group 1] `href='`
- [Group 2] `https://www.sans.org/webcasts/archive/2013`

http://regex101.com/r/gO8vV7 here is a working example

Comment: Don't forget to forbid white characters (that can not be inside an href attribute)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte It's best not to do that just incase the original programmer is putting in illegal characters. So long as it's not followed by the quote or `>` delimiter, it'll get captured.

Comment: Why not but if you have an other attribute after this doesn't work.